# Call chain for async/await ... await the awaitable or return the awaitable?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Given an async method:

```
public async Task<int> InnerAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return 123;
}
```

And calling it through an intermediate method, should the intermediate method await the async method `IntermediateA` or merely return the Task `IntermediateB`?

```
public async Task<int> IntermediateA()
{
    return await InnerAsync();
}

private Task<int> IntermediateB()
{
    return InnerAsync();
}
```

As best I can tell with the debugger, both appear to work exactly the same, but it seems to me that IntermediateB should perform better by avoiding one more await entry in the state machine.

Is that right?

Comment: The difference is in exception handling. To understand that better I suggest you try to throw an exception from the inner function and see how things work.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't consider exception handling at all.

Comment: "it seems to me that IntermediateB should perform better" - yes, but the difference will be a few nanoseconds. It could also save a few dozen bytes in the generated binary.

Comment: I suggest you to read [Eliding Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is subtle differences in this two approaches. If you `await` failed task the exception will thrown in that method, but if you pass the task thought that method and then `await` it, the exception will be thrown in the consumer method. Another difference is more rare, in case of consumer awaiting the task and if it occurred with delay, the task can be finished at the await point and bypass the state machine.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't consider exception handling at all.

Comment: What about performance? Is this not creating two state machines (awaiting inner)?

Comment: Without a try/catch, the exception will propagate to the caller anyway. Can you point out a substantial practical difference?