# asp.net core mvc middle ware simple case

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to wrap my head around the middleware concept of Asp.Net core MVC.

I understand that the following two are identical.

```
app.Use(next => next);

app.Use(next => { return next; });
```

Now I want to understand if the following is also identical. If so how.

```
app.Use(next => 
{
    return async context =>
    {
        await next(context);
    };
});
```

There is no compile time error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although they do produce the same result, technically there is a slight difference. By adding the extra `async` method, an extra state machine will be created which does not cause significant changes in performance but is worth considering.

Basically it's very similar concern as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47624317/call-chain-for-async-await-await-the-awaitable-or-return-the-awaitable).

Comment: There's more to this than just [Eliding Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html). The OP's last example creates a new delegate that wraps up the delegate that's passed in, whereas the first examples pass the incoming delegate straight back out as-is. For example, `app.Use(next => context => next(context));` also works.